# Pseudo Thomae's function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R^{3}} \to \mathbb{R}$ with
$f(x,y,z)$ =\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{q},&\text{if $(x,y,z)=(\frac{p}{q},\frac{r}{l},\frac{m}{n})$ with $p,r,m\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $q,l,n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus{0}$}\\
0,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}

I know that this function is not continuous at $(x,y,z)=(\frac{p}{q},\frac{r}{l},\frac{m}{n})$, using the discontinuity sequence theorem, but I want to know if the partial derivatives exist at this point, in the case of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(\frac{p}{q},\frac{r}{l},\frac{m}{n})$ my doubt is when I consider $t$ tends to zero, $t$ could have irrationals and rationls numbers so I dont know if the partial derivative exist or not, I have the same doubt at $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$.
In the case of continuity at $(0,0,0)$ does it works as same as Thomae's function, I mean It would be continuous?

Comment: Your function, as written, is not well-defined. Is the $p/q$ in least terms in the definition?

Comment: can you give me more details to the function be well defined? just p/q have to be in least terms? really appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function $f$ with a rational argument $p/q$ is *well-defined* if

$$p/q=a/b \implies f(p/q)=f(a/b)$$

The issue here is that rational numbers have many *representatives*, e.g. $1/2=2/4=...$. So, does $1/2$ map to $1/2$ or to $1/4$?

As you have it written there, the function you wrote is not well-defined.

I believe the function you meant to write down is the function $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x,y,z)=0$ when at least one argument is irrational, and $f(x,y,z)=T(x)$ otherwise, where $T:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is Thomae's function.

Your function may be written $f(x,y,z)=T(x)D(y)D(z)$ where $D:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is Dirichlet's function (the indicator of the rationals). Therefore, your function has no partial derivatives at any point as $T,D$ are nowhere differentiable.